# Mobile number format

Tags: jquery

How can I transform this text field using jQuery to format mobile numbers? What I mean here is that when users enter mobile number into the input field, jQuery should it.
Example is when 08098112233 is entered, it is formatted to 2348098112233

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" />
</form>
```

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please edit your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: @Kyll: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the first character is a zero, if so replace it with 234. Note that the string replace method only will replace the first occurrence by default.

```js
 $( '#button' ).click(function() {
 
  var nr = $( '#nr' ).val();
  nr  = nr.indexOf('0') == 0 ? nr.replace('0','234') : nr;
  
  $( '#result' ).html(nr);
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="nr" />
<button type="button" id="button">Get</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: You've got it all. Cool stuff

Comment: Please do not answer blatantly off-topic questions, it can make it look like it's okay to ask them. Check the [help] to know what is on-topic and what is not.